# How to connect Flask app to SQLite DB running in Docker?

Tags: python, docker, sqlite, docker-compose

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"

services:
  sqlite3:
    image: nouchka/sqlite3:latest
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./db/:/root/db/
  app:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: build/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ../:/app
    command: pipenv run gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:5000 --reload app:app
```

Now how do I get my Flask app to connect to my dockerized db?

`SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'`  (I'm not sure what to put here to connect to the Docker image db)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can share the volumes between containers.

```
version: "3"

services:
  sqlite3:
    image: nouchka/sqlite3:latest
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./db/:/root/db/
  app:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: build/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ../:/app
      - ./db/:/my/sqlite/path/ # Here is the change
    command: pipenv run gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:5000 --reload app:app
```

Now the files inside `./db/` directory is accessible from your python image too, so you can set URI like this:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:////my/sqlite/path/'
```

Comment: Hi @meshkati can you pls elaborate on what is `/my/sqlite/path/` is it the path of sqllite in the local setup?

Comment: @Mudits left side of `:` is your local path, and the right side is the path on the container.